# Changing the Colour of a Progress bar in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is it possible to modify certain shapes and change their colours? such as the progress bar in visio?

I need to change it to red

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'Open' the control first, as it consists of multiple elements.

Right-click and Group > Open Progress Bar

Open up the 'Format Shape' sidebar, and now you can edit the fill.

Comment: My bad, i didn't know you could go into the grouped shape. Can I edit my answer?

Comment: I think so, I'll then remove my comment.